# Chebishev theorem implementation

Tags: probability

How many independent experiments do we need so that we could conclude that probability of inequality $|\frac{X_n}{n} -p| < 0.01$ being true is at least $0.979$, where $X_n$ is number of positive outcomes in $n$ experiments and $p=0.03$ is probability of positive outcome in one experiment. Use Chebyshev inequality to solve this.

First off, this is Chebyshev inequality $$P(|X - E(X)|< \epsilon) >1-\frac{Var(X)}{\epsilon^2}$$

We can say that this experiment has Bernoulli's disribution (or Poisson's perhaps, but i'll go with Bernoulli)

so $E(X)=np=0.03n$ and $Var(X)=npq=0.0291n$ but in this case, i have $\frac{X_n}{n}$ instead of $X$ in the inequality that has to be proven (or $n$ to be found to be precise) so that means that i should look for $$E(\frac{X_n}{n})$$ and $$Var(\frac{X_n}{n})$$ but the problem is, i don't know how to find those values. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that $P\left(\left|\frac{X_n}{n} - p\right|\leq 0.01\right)\geq 0.979$.

The $p$ you provide is the *sample mean* for a particular experiment. Let's call these experiments $S_i$. Hence $X_n = S_1 + \dots + S_n$ where $E[S_i] = p$. Hence $E\left[\frac{X_n}{n}\right] = p$. Hence $E[X_n] = np$ and $Var(X_n) = np(1-p)$ (just like you pointed out!).

$$\begin{split}
P\left(\left|\frac{X_n}{n} - p\right|\leq 0.01\right) &= P\left(\frac{|X_n-np|}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\leq 0.01\sqrt{\frac{n}{p(1-p)}}\right)\\ &= P\left(\frac{|X_n-E[X_n]|}{\sqrt{Var(X_n)}}\leq 0.01\sqrt{\frac{n}{p(1-p)}}\right)
\end{split}
$$
Now, by the central limit theorem, $Y_n = \frac{|X_n-E[X_n]|}{\sqrt{Var(X_n)}}$ converges in distribution to the normal distribution, and you can come up with a value for $n$ this way. And it is one way to verify that the Chebyshev value is correct.

Now, $Y_n$ having mean $0$ and variance $1$ we have that 
$$
P\left (Y_n\leq 0.01\sqrt{\frac{n}{p(1-p)}}\right)\geq 1-\frac{1}{\epsilon}
$$
where $\epsilon = 0.01\sqrt{\frac{n}{p(1-p)}}$.

Now you simply need to solve for $n$.

Comment: How do you know that $Y_n$ has mean zero and variance one?

Comment: Well, calculate its expectation and its variance. Also, I made a small mistake. there should have been no modulus when I defined $Y_n$. $E[Y_n] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{Var(X_n)}}E\left[X_n-E[X_n]\right] = 0$, and similar for the variance. Let me know if this clarifies things.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, first off, i don't see where formula  $Y_n = \frac{|X_n-E[X_n]|}{\sqrt{Var(X_n)}}$    comes from, and then i don't know how should i calculate the mean of that variable.

Comment: The formula comes from the manipulation we did within the probability. The idea for it comes from "normalising" $X_n$ to $Y_n$. I calculated the mean for $Y_n$ for you in my previous comment. You just need to do that for $Var(Y_n)$. Bear in mind that $E[X_n]$ and $Var(X_n)$ are just some constants and you can apply the linearity of expectation and the quadratic of the variance.

Comment: If you'll still have issues, I will post the full solution, but it is best you try working it out yourself.

Comment: I see, that's the formula for normalisation when dealing with gaussian distribution, we do that in some cases when we need proper values so we could read the probability table (i suppose that's how it's called), anyway, i think i got it, i'll try to do it all by my self now to see if i fully understood it, thanks for the effort!